# What is the difference between data type String and [String]?

Tags: swift, string, xcode

I am currently coding in swift, and often assign String-type variables from a list of Strings.

For example:

```
nameList : [String] = ["Bob", "Don", "Ron"]    
var name : String = nameList [2]
```

But I often get an error saying: Data type [String] cannot be assigned to type String.

I'm really confused with this error, because I thought an element taken from a string list is the same data type with a string variable.

Can someone explain the difference between type String and [String]? Thanks!

Comment: You may need to have `nameList[2]` (without a space). It might be being parsed weird because of the space.

Comment: One is a value, the other is an array of values, `[]` denotes an array. What's the problematic code that you need explanations for?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This code appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` refers to an individual string, whereas `[String]` is an array of strings. I think your error may be that you have done:

```
var name : String = nameList [2]
```

Where you should have done:

```
var name : String = nameList[2]
```

I assume that in the first instance it thinks you are setting `name` as 'nameList' because of the space, so `namelist[2]` should make it clear that you mean the second value in the array which is an individual String.

Edit: After testing the space should not cause a problem.
Is it really:

```
nameList : [String] = ["Bob", "Don", "Ron"]
var name : String = nameList [2]
```

As opposed to:

```
var nameList : [String] = ["Bob", "Don", "Ron"]
var name : String = nameList [2]
    print(name)
```

Please provide more code so we can see the context.

Comment: The space makes no difference (at least not in my quick test with Xcode 9.4.1)

Comment: Thank you, I can't comment on the question, but they need to provide more code. "But I often get an error saying: Data type [String] cannot be assigned to type String." Is this a real example of the error, or did they make this from memory?

Comment: Thank you so much! that appears to be the solution. It's fixed now!

Comment: @TheArchangel Great, if so please accept the answer :)